# jQuery fadeIn div show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs

```
<div id="over1"> Over 1 </div>
<div id="over2"> Over 2 </div>
<div id="over3"> Over 3 </div>

<div id="image1"><img src="1.jpg></div>
<div id="image2"><img src="2.jpg></div>
<div id="image3"><img src="3.jpg></div>
```

and I am trying to build a jQuery script so when the user moves the mouse arrow over over1 then 1.jpg fades in and then when the user moves the mouse arrow over over2 then 2.jpg appears and then when the user moves mouse arrow over Over 3 then 3.jpg appears.  However, only one image appears in the spot.

Is the below correct?

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

$('over1').mouseover(  function() {  $('image1').fadeIn(1000);  }  );

$('over1').mouseleave(  function() {  $('image1').fadeOut(1000);  }  );

$('over2').mouseover(  function() {  $('image2').fadeIn(1000);  }  );

$('over2').mouseleave(  function() {  $('image2').fadeOut(1000);  }  );

$('over3').mouseover(  function() {  $('image3').fadeIn(1000);  }  );

$('over3').mouseleave(  function() {  $('image3').fadeOut(1000);  }  );

</script>
```

Comment: Can you put your whole code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to toggle classes (its much more efficient) and then transition using CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/thechrisjordan/ZzUWD/19/

```
var $targets = $('#targets').children();

$targets.each(function (idx, element) {
    $(this)  
        .on('mouseover', function () {
            $('#image' + (idx + 1)).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
        })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
            $('#image' + (idx + 1)).removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#over1').mouseover(
    function() { $('#image1').fadeIn(1000); }
);
$('#over1').mouseleave(
    function() { $('#image1').fadeOut(1000); }
);
$('#over2').mouseover(
    function(){ $('#image2').fadeIn(1000); }
);
$('#over2').mouseleave(
    function(){ $('#image2').fadeOut(1000); }
);
$('#over3').mouseover(
    function(){ $('#image3').fadeIn(1000); }
);
$('#over3').mouseleave(
    function(){ $('#image3').fadeOut(1000); }
);
```

OR

```
$('#over1').hover(
    function(){ $('#image1').fadeIn(1000); },
    function(){ $('#image1').fadeOut(1000); }
);
$('#over2').hover(
    function(){ $('#image2').fadeIn(1000); },
    function(){ $('#image2').fadeOut(1000); }
);
$('#over3').hover(
    function(){ $('#image2').fadeIn(1000); },
    function(){ $('#image2').fadeOut(1000); }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution can help you.

HTML code

```
<div id="over1" class="myDivs"> Over 1 </div>
<div id="over2" class="myDivs"> Over 2 </div>
<div id="over3" class="myDivs"> Over 3 </div>

<div id="image1" class="myImg"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/591276-arrow-right-16.png"> image 1 </div>
<div id="image2" class="myImg"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/591276-arrow-right-16.png"> image 2 </div>
<div id="image3" class="myImg"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/591276-arrow-right-16.png"> image 3 </div>
```

jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.myImg').hide();
$('.myDivs').on('hover',function() {
    $('.myImg').hide();
    var $$ = $(this),
        getId = $$.attr('id'),
        imageId = getId.substr(-1);
    $('#image'+imageId).fadeIn();
});

});
```

Example Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/63khB/

Comment: if you wish to use 'click' effect you can simple change 'hover' to 'click'.